# Performance issue with $uibModal (angular JS)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-modal

we are seeing performance issue with $uibModal.open , its taking around 40 secs to open new Modal. any one has any idea why its taking time to open a modal ..?

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation : false,
        templateUrl : 'partials/modals/modalFormDefault.html',
        controller : 'relationFormModalCtrl',
        size:'md',
        backdrop  : 'static',
        keyboard  : false,
        resolve : {
            formProperties : function() {
                return angular.copy(linkFormProperties);
            },
            entity : function () {
                return 'Create';
            },
            relationData : function(){
                return relationTableDetails;
            },
            tableData : function(){
                return $scope.relTableOptions.data;
            },
            parentEntity : function(){
                return parentEntity;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by removing ng-repeat from html file